# mobile application phonegap flight mode/alarm control?

Tags: cordova, mobile

is it possible to do a mobile application in phonegap that retrieves calendar entries from an online API,
and according to the calendar entry,
it would set an alarm few hours before the calendar entry, and then automatically go into flight mode?

it's a basic app for pilots,
but a bit new to mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

Since PhoneGap allows you to [add plugins to an existing projects](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) you can do anything you could do in a native, Objective C based application. But the idea behind PhoneGap is to write once and deploy on multiple devices, and if you are going to customize the application for iOS then you might as well write an actual iOS application.

Comment: i would like to create the same functionality on ios and android...get a calendar date/time , and automatically have the app set an alarm and go in flight mode when needed..is that possible ?

Comment: Yes that is possible. Check out [PhoneGap Plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) - especially, LocalNotications and CalendarPlugin. You can modify the functionality of the generic plugins to fit your needs.